# How to modify javascript object with attributs names stocked in an Array

Tags: json, node.js

I'm working with Node.js and I've got a jsonFile which allow me to create an object:

```
var dateFile = './Dictionnary/lastUpdate.json';
var dateObj = jsonfile.readFileSync(dateFile);
```

The object is this one:

```
var dateObj = {
  "l2D": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "CU": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "l2G": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "la1": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "la2": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "lru": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "nu3": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "DictionnaryTime": "2018-07-30T07:59:47.000Z"
}
```

And I want to update the values of the attributs with a script like this:

```
var citiesDictNames = ['CU', 'l2D', 'l2G', 'la1', 'la2', 'lru', 'nu3'];

for (i = 0; i < csvCitiesNames.length; i++) {
  newDate = function(...);
  var name = citiesDictNames[i];
  dateObj.name = newDate;
  jsonfile.writeFile(dateFile, dateObj, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('LastModified Date updated');
    }
  });
}
```

But the result is this object:

```
var dateObj = {
  "l2D": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "CU": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "l2G": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "la1": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "la2": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "lru": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "nu3": "2018-07-10T08:45:03.000Z",
  "DictionnaryTime": "2018-07-30T07:59:47.000Z",
  "name": "2018-07-04T16:12:43.000Z",
}
```

When I replace `dateObj.name` by `dateObj.l2D` or an other value that's working but I don't succeed when the values are in an arrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `dateObj[name]` access syntax.

[Javascript Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)